# C++ class member scope when instatiated object in constructor

Tags: c++, object, constructor, scope

I have this code in class constructor:

```
MqttSensorInterface::MqttSensorInterface(Client& client, String sensorTopic)
{
  this->mqttClient = PubSubClient(client);
  this->sensorTopic = sensorTopic;
  this->askMeasureTopic = sensorTopic + "/askmeasure";
  this->publishMeasureTopic = sensorTopic + "/measure";
}
```

But just after the constructor is used when a new `MqttSensorInterface` object is created, the `PubSubClient` object instantiated in the constructor is destructed (`PubSubClient` destructor is called). I am new with **C++** and dont know if there is something wrong with this code. As the `PubSubClient` object is instantiated in constructor but the class member `mqttClient` is set to be this object, which is its scope?

PubSubClient constructor code:

```
PubSubClient::PubSubClient(Client& client) {
    this->_state = MQTT_DISCONNECTED;
    setClient(client);
    this->stream = NULL;
    this->bufferSize = 0;
    setBufferSize(MQTT_MAX_PACKET_SIZE);
    setKeepAlive(MQTT_KEEPALIVE);
    setSocketTimeout(MQTT_SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
}
```

**EDIT**

Solved by using member initializer list this way:

```
MqttSensorInterface::MqttSensorInterface( Client& client, String sensorTopic): mqttClient(client)
```

Comment: `PubSubClient(wifiClient);` creates a new object, which is then copied or moved to the member variable. The original one gets destroyed when the constructor finishes

Comment: It depend of the implementation of `PubSubClient::operator=(PubSbuClient const&)`. Maybe there is shared resources ?

Comment: If that's a problem to you, it's just another reason to [favor member initializer lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list) over assignment in the c'tor.

Comment: No, please don't. At over 300 reputation you should know well enough that important details about your problem (like code) belong in the post body, not in comments. [edit] the code into your question.

Comment: without a [mcve] this question is unclear. The code you posted can be fine and it can be not fine, depending on the code you didn't post. I would suggest you to write a smaller toy example and ask the same quesiton for that, because too much is missing here

Comment: Yes, I edited the post body and the PubSubClient constructor code. I have solved the issue by using member initializer list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the body of the constructor

```
MqttSensorInterface::MqttSensorInterface(String sensorTopic)
{
  WiFiClient wiFiClient;
  this->mqttClient = PubSubClient(wifiClient);
  this->sensorTopic = sensorTopic;
  this->askMeasureTopic = sensorTopic + "/askmeasure";
  this->publishMeasureTopic = sensorTopic + "/measure";
}
```

gets the control the data member mqttClient is already created using the default constructor  `PubSubClient` provided that in the class definition there is no explicit initializer of the data member,

So inside the body in this statement

```
this->mqttClient = PubSubClient(wifiClient);
```

there is created a temporary object of the type `PubSubClient` by means of explicit call of the constructor `PubSubClient(wifiClient)` and this temporary object is assigned to the data member `this->mqttClient` using either the copy assignment operator or the move assignment operator. At the end of execution of the statement the temporary object is destroyed.

You could initialize the data member in the mem-initializer list of the constructor during the construction  of the data member if it is possible.

Comment: And If I use `new PubSubClient(wiFiClient)` then it wont be destroyed until explicitly destroyed right?

Comment: @MABC I have not understood what you mean. In this statement this->mqttClient = PubSubClient(wifiClient); there is created a temporary object PubSubClient(wifiClient);  that is assigned to the data member. After the assignment the temporary object will be destroyed.

Comment: It makes a difference if instead using this statement `this->mqttClient = PubSubClient(wifiClient);` it is used this one `this->mqttClient = **new** PubSubClient(wifiClient);` ?

Comment: MABC: Those are not equivalent so, yes, there's a difference, but probably not the diff you want. Make a [mcve] so we get all the info we need.

Comment: @MABC Of course there is a difference. The second case just is invalid if there is used the operator new because  this->mqttClient  is not a pointer is it?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yes I mean if mqttClient is declared as pointer to PubSubClientObject. Then the object wont be destroyed until it is explicitly destroyed via free(mqttClient) right?